# Index.php cannot access private files

Tags: php, file, model-view-controller, permissions, directory

I developed a php MVC framework from scratch and my index.php cannot access some files when I change the permissions. I use fillezilla and the only file permissions I can set are read, write and execute checkboxes for each group (owner, group and public). If I uncheck all the public ones then I get an error, but if I leave the public->execute box checked, index.php finds the files. **I don't have public/private folder setting so is this setting ok or what should I do??**

Comment: the permissions need to be those accessible by whatever user is running your webserver. For instance if you are running apache under linux you will need to make sure apache has access to those files. This can be easily achieved by using ACLs.

Comment: I googled ACL quickly and I know how to make a login script in php and control who goes where, but I want index.php to be the only thing that can access certain files/folders. Up until now I thought anyone can read public files and only files on the site can read/require private files/folders, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The server is apache on linux any suggestions??

Comment: that's not how file permissions work. apache is running as a specific user, which is usually `apache`, and also under a specific group which also is usually `apache`. Between those two the permissions are defined. As far as permissions go on your files, you should pretty much limit it to just user/group permissions and always nothing for public.

Comment: if you want to restrict index.php to accessing only specific files, then what you want to do is move those files into a non-web accessible path, and then have index.php serve up the files. However you need to be very cautious of doing this, as if you don't properly sanitize the input then the user could be reading any file on the file system that the file permissions allow apache to read.